# Non gui mode does not provide advantage in my test in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

When i run a test in gui mode with 500 threads and 10s ramp up time, the cpu usage was %80 - 85 and memory was 25gb. (This cpu is the one on which Jmeter is used, not the server cpu.)

When i run the same test in non gui mode the usages **were the same**.

Note1 : in gui mode "jp gc perfmon metrics collector" listener is active. in non gui mode, the same. another listener is not used.

Note2 : cpu specs : 96gb ram, logical processors = 40

The related listeners reports are attached.[GuiModeActiveThread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfLsF.jpg),  [NonGuiModeActiveThread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqKeC.jpg), [GuiModePerfMon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtnzK.jpg), [NonGuiModePerfMon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUQbP.jpg), [GuiModeAggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RktA6.jpg), [NonGuiModeAggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFcaV.jpg).

Comment: Did you follow [Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You ran your test for how long? If test duration is 10 seconds, number of Samplers is low and response time is low as well the actual concurrency was not 400, it was rather around 40, you can double check it using [Active Threads Over Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) for more detailed explanation.
2. I wouldn't expect much higher CPU and RAM consumption in non-GUI mode, I would expect higher [**Throughput**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) - the number of requests per second (as long as you don't have any artificial pauses introduced by [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)). JMeter GUI per se doesn't consume a lot of resources, but it can greatly slow JMeter down because refreshing/re-drawing the GUI is happening in the single thread

Comment: i run the test with 500 users in gui mode and non gui mode. then attached the test results to this question body. could you examine them. And i realized now that, after running the test in gui mode, the memory(RAM) will not decrease. what could be reason of this? As i closed the Jmeter, then memory starts to decrease.

Comment: What do you want from me? My point 2 is assumption that in non-GUI mode you have higher throughput and your screenshots confirm my guess. So the only "examination" result I can give you is a piece of advice to activate your Windows

Comment: do you know the reason of the second question? unless i closed the Jmeter gui, the memory (ram) wont be decrease, after the test that is ran in gui mode.